# Ternary operator to minimize code

Tags: c#

How I can minimize the following code using ternary operator

```
if (toolButtonState.New == 1)
    ts.Items["tsbNew"].Enabled = true;
else
    ts.Items["tsbNew"].Enabled = false;
```

Please provide an implementation

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you think it is necessary to change this code? If you want to solicit improvements to working code, you should  post to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You can just simplify it like this:

```
ts.Items["tsbNew"].Enabled = (toolButtonState.New == 1);
```

Technically, you could use a ternary operator like this, but there's no reason to:

```
ts.Items["tsbNew"].Enabled = (toolButtonState.New == 1) ? true : false;
```

Typically, ternary expressions are more useful if the expressions after the `?` and `:` do not simply evaluate to `true` and `false`, such as with the following:

```
someControl.ForeColor = (toolButtonState.New == 1) ? Color.Red : Color.Black;
```

Keep in mind that if the expressions are more than a simple one-liner, your code may be more readable if you just stick with old-fashioned `if/else` statements and curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

The [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is of the form:

```
(condition) ? (if true) : (if false)
```

So a ternary on your piece of code would turn in to:

```
ts.Items["tsbNew"].Enabled = (toolButtonState.New == 1) ? true : false;
```

You will notice though that the if true value is `true` and the if false value is `false`. You can simply remove the ternary statement and it will do the same thing by setting `.Enabled` to the result of the condition:

```
ts.Items["tsbNew"].Enabled = (toolButtonState.New == 1);
```